# what is the meaning of object as an argument of an event

Tags: angular

I was trying to understand a piece of code but couldn't able to understand.
What is the meaning or significant of the below snippet of code `'onSelect({ selected })'`

```
<ngx-datatable
          [rows]="rows"
          [selected]="selected"
          [selectionType]="SelectionType.single"
          (select)="onSelect($event)">
        </ngx-datatable>

export class SingleSelectionComponent {
  rows = [];
  selected = [];
  columns: any[] = [{ prop: 'name' }, { name: 'Company' }, { name: 'Gender' }];

  constructor() {
    this.fetch(data => {
      this.selected = [data[2]];
      this.rows = data;
    });
  }

  onSelect({ selected }) {
    console.log('Select Event', selected, this.selected);
  }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of this `onSelect({ selected })`?

Comment: You are de-structuring the object. Please find the reference to learn more on it :
https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6

Comment: it means pluck the "selected" property from object that passed into event.  check object destructuring : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/destructuring.html

Answer (score 1):

It is called as Destructuring assignment. Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment.

It helps you in picking the required properties only rather than the entire object, In your case the required property is just the "selected" property from the MouseEvent Object.

Answer (score 0):

This is a so-called "destructuring" or deconstruction of the data passed.

It receives the entire MouseEvent, this way only the MouseEvent.selected is passed to the function to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically this is called Destructuring assignment. It is used to
> unpack unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into
> distinct variables.

Lets simplify

For ex.

you have an object `obj` and and a function `onSelect`

```
let obj = {'name': 'user1', 'rank': '1', 'selected': true};
```

> with Destructuring

```
function onSelect({ selected }) {         // Unpacking fields from objects passed as function parameter
    console.log(selected);
}
```

> with out Destructuring

```
function onSelect( param) {     
    console.log(param.selected);
}
```

we can call `onSelect(obj);`

> as you see with out Destructuring we have to use dot notation to
> access that properties. so to reduce the code we can directly access
> properties with the help of Destructuring

For more info please check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Hope this helps you!